# Read a file and have numbers in between two numbers read be a certain thing

Tags: java, graph, maps, bufferedreader

Say I have this data file. I'm trying to draw out a map with the nodes as intersections which connects two roads and draw a road to between them. The first two numbers in coords is the lat/lon of nodeID1 and the last two (bottom right) are of nodeID2. The two coords in the middle are where the road changes direction, so like the point where the road curves pretty much. Sometimes, as you know, roads have more than one curves or like directions (windy roads) and so I would have more of those coords for those road segments in between the two nodes. I'm wondering how would I read the coords in between the nodes and store them in a collection as "road segments"/"curving points" etc ? How would I go about this with a buffered reade?

BufferedReader data = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(roadFile));

```
roadID  length             nodeID1  nodeID2   coords
17134   0.22322055914578026 12420   12556    -36.88853  174.72218   -36.88954                 
                                              174.72361  -36.88992  174.72398
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening the `roadFile` using your `BufferedReader`, you can parse the input line by line using the `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` method. Each line is returned as a `String`. You can then use a `StringTokenizer` to break the `String` into parts based on a delimiter (e.g. a tab `\t` or a whitespace character). Here's some example code:

```
        try(BufferedReader data = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(roadFile));) {
            String line = null;
            String delim = "\t";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line, delim);
                while(tok.hasMoreTokens()){
                    String nextToken = tok.nextToken();
                    //do stuff with the nextToken String
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks Austin, that makes sense. I just need to read up on parsing. Thanks for the example, it's helping me learn this! @Austin D